# Symfony2 - What is the best way of creating global text files?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, global-variables

I have something like 300 strings in an array and would like to compare if a given string is one of those in the array.

For example, my string to compare is `"blabla"`.
If this string exist in the array of 300 strings, do something. To do that, I will use the php function: `in_array();`

Now, my question is: **Where do I store this huge array?** In a file? If so, where do I store the file? Is symfony managing that somehow?

Comment: Hm, interesting point...

Comment: If those 300 strings are always the same, you could use doctrine-fixture to load the database when you install your project somewhere and then use doctrine cache when you first retrieve the data. That's probably how I would do it

Comment: Ok, but what if I will clear the cache later?

Comment: You would just reload the content in the cache from the database again :)

Comment: Hm, no, this is to risky...

Comment: Are your 300 strings static or dynamic ? (they can change ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is fixed and will not change ...

```
final class StringProvider
{
   const strings = array(
     // ... array here
   )

   public function match($string)
   {
      return in_array($string,self::strings);
   }
}
```

Access the constant with

```
StringProvider::strings
```

... or use the function

```
$stringProvider = new StringProvider();
if ( $stringProvider->match($string) ) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

use Zend OPCache or APC to store the file in memory ... will be the fatest option.